# Problem with my Python code: IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python, loops, bioinformatics, index-error

Recently I was working on a python challenge where I needed to create a function that was capable of transcribing DNA to mRNA, but every time I run the code I receive the same error message:

if dna[y] == "A":
IndexError: string index out of range

Can anyone help me? Below is a sample of my code.

```
global y
y = 0
global rna
rna = ""
def dna_to_rna(dna):
    global y
    global rna
    for i in range(len(dna)):
        if dna[y] == "A":
            rna += "U"
        elif dna[y] == "T":
            rna += "A"
        elif dna[y] == "G":
            rna += "C"
        else:
            rna += "G"
        y += 1
    return rna
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  how did you define the variable dna? It is not in the code sample you posted. Thanks

Comment: Your error is telling you that `dna[y]` does not exist. `y` is probably way too large. Also, it's very strange to use `global`. The fact that you're running into problems *and* people here cannot help you is a good hint to not use `global`, *ever*.

Comment: First of all avoid naming variables as global, this is considered bad programming practice.

Comment: @smile It looks like the variable dna is a string that's inputted as a parameter in the function.

Comment: @RaiyanChowdhury  I know using global is strange but I  just defined thease variables  this way just so  I dont encounter some problems like the y and rna variables being interpreted as local variables, but anyway, I will try  not to commit this kind of bad practice again.

Comment: Perhaps you should post a sample of your `dna` variable along with a full Traceback of the error message. Hint: what exactly is 'y', have you tried `if dna[i] == ...` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of extra variables and you don't need 'global' modifiers in your code. I've done some reformatting to your code, try this:

```
def dna_to_rna(dna: str) -> str:
  rna = ""
  for i in range(len(dna)):
      if dna[i] == "A":
          rna += "U"
      elif dna[i] == "T":
          rna += "A"
      elif dna[i] == "G":
          rna += "C"
      elif dna[i] == "C":
          rna += "G"
      else:
          return "Invalid Sequence!"
  return rna
```

Comment: Thanks Raiyan, the code worked perfectly! From now on I won't use the global modifier anymore and will also try to eliminate those extra variables.